# Stress-energy-momentum tensor for a "on-shell" Dirac field

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dirac-equation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

[Hilbert energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is generally defined as

$$T_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} = -2\delta\mathcal{L} + g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L} \delta g^{\mu\nu}$$

where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lagrangian density of the field. Now if the field is "on-shell", then according to this [Physics SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/678463/332923) [comment below Eq. 3] and this paper [[Non-Existence of Black Hole Solutions for a Spherically Symmetric, Static Einstein-Dirac-Maxwell System](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9810048), Eq. 3.8], in case of a "on-shell" Dirac field, the second term in the above expression, $g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L} \delta g^{\mu\nu}$ will be zero.

But in these papers [[Cosmological model with non-minimally coupled fermionic field](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5155) (Eq. 8) and [Spinors, Inflation, and Non-Singular Cyclic Cosmologies](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0301129) (Eq. 12)], the aforementioned $g_{\mu\nu} \mathcal{L} \delta g^{\mu\nu}$ term for "on-shell" Dirac field has been kept as it is, without making it zero!

Therefore,

1. Which one is correct? Will the aforementioned term be zero?
2. If so, then why?

Comment: For the proper approach to the stress tensor for spinor fields, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315830/

Comment: Thank you, but this answer has not addressed the issue of "on-shell" Dirac field. My question is not about how to derive the stress-energy tensor for a spinor field, but rather  it concerns about the fate of $g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}\delta g^{\mu\nu}$ term if that field is "on-shell".

Comment: Right. Your question is about the fate of a term that doesn't appear in the proper approach. The derivative acting on a spinor cannot be generalized to curved space using only a metric.

Comment: Actually scratch that. I think the term shows up in the papers you linked simply because their Lagrangians have a potential. The Phys.SE answer by contrast deals with the minimally coupled Dirac Lagrangian.