# Can you assume the energy-momentum tensor is symmetric if you only impose Lorentz symmetry?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The proof showing that the energy-momentum tensor is symmetric uses the fact that $\partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ due to translation symmetry, the definition of the conserved current and that $\partial_\nu J^{\mu\nu\rho}=0$ due to Lorentz symmetry:

> \begin{equation}
> 0=\partial_\nu J^{\mu\nu\rho} = \partial_\nu (T^{\mu\nu}x^\rho - T^{\rho\nu}x^\mu) = x^\rho \partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu} + T^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu x^\rho - x^\mu \partial_\nu T^{\rho\nu} - T^{\rho\nu}\partial_\nu x^\mu = T^{\mu\rho}-T^{\rho\mu}
> \end{equation}

My question is: is it possible to prove the energy-momentum tensor is symmetric only assuming Lorentz symmetry and not translation symmetry?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315830/84967

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is the stress-energy tensor symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68564/2451) More on [symmetry of the SEM tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symmetry+stress-energy-momentum-tensor).